# Split vector at max value in Clojure -- better way?

Tags: clojure

Newbie question:

How to split a vector of numbers at and including the first instance of the maximum value in it?

So, from this `[1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1]`, get `[1 2 3 4 5] [4 3 2 1]`.

The way I'm doing it seems overly complex:

```
(def up5 [1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1])
(split-at (inc (.indexOf up5 (apply max up5))) up5) ; => [1 2 3 4 5] [4 3 2 1]
```

Does that seem a little awkward? For example using the defined vector three times. And do we need to use Java to get the index?

What would be a better, more idiomatic, or more performant way?

Thanks.

Comment: More performant would be with `reduce-kv` to avoid the `.indexOf` call. But it's even longer than your version.

Comment: Is the input always a vector? Do you require the result to be seq/vector/whatever?

Comment: I don't think it would matter. Anyway I'm not using this code for any purpose beyond trying to improve...

Comment: @Mallory-Erik I was too concerned about the *performant* part, apparently you are not looking for dead performance. :D tnoda's solution is idiomatic enough already.

Comment: @Andre using `reduce-kv` would prevent using the result on non-associative data structures (for example on lists or sets)

Comment: @Andre Is `reduce-kv` faster than `.indexOf`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(defn split-at-max [v]
  (when (seq v)
    (let [m (apply max v)
          point (inc (count (reduce (fn [a b] (if (> m b) (conj a b) 
                                              (reduced a))) [] v)))]
      ((juxt #(take point %) #(drop point %)) v))))

(split-at-max [1 2 9 2 -7  33 3 4 53 1 22 4 -44 444 3 2 3 0 -21])
;;=> [(1 2 9 2 -7 33 3 4 53 1 22 4 -44 444) (3 2 3 0 -21)]
(split-at-max [])
;;=> nil
(split-at-max [26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33])
;;=> [(26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33) ()]
(split-at-max [33 32 31 30 29 28 27 26])
;;=> [(33) (32 31 30 29 28 27 26)]
;; works also with sets and lists:
(split-at-max '(1 2 9 2 -7  33 3 4 53 1 22 4 -44 444 3 2 3 0 -21))
;;=> [(1 2 9 2 -7 33 3 4 53 1 22 4 -44 444) (3 2 3 0 -21)]
(split-at-max '())
;;=> nil
(split-at-max (hash-set))
;;=> nil
(split-at-max (sorted-set))
;;=> nil
(split-at-max (sorted-set 1 2 9 2 -7 33 3 4 53 1 22 4 -44 444 3 2 3 0 -21))
;;=> [(-44 -21 -7 0 1 2 3 4 9 22 33 53 444) ()]
(split-at-max (hash-set 1 2 9 2 -7 33 3 4 53 1 22 4 -44 444 3 2 3 0 -21))
;;=> [(0 1 4 -21 33 22 -44 3 2 444) (-7 9 53)]
```

another similar way using `split-with` to split at the max-point (also need to do a `seq` on the input first, if there is a chance to have empty collections):

```
(let [v [1 2 9 2 -7 33 3 4 53 1 22 4 -44 444 3 2 3 0 -21]
      m (apply max v)]
  ((juxt #(concat (first %) [(first (second %))]) #(rest (second %)))
   (split-with (partial > m) v)))
;;=> [(1 2 9 2 -7 33 3 4 53 1 22 4 -44 444) (3 2 3 0 -21)]
```

Comment: You first version fails if the max element is the first or last one. Also fails for the empty vector

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing that out, i have changed it using `reduce` to find the max-point instead of `partition-by`

Answer (score 2):

alternative variant (just for fun):

- you generate the sequence of tuples with split-position (item's index + 1) and item itself
- find the tuple with max item using `max-key`
- split your collection at the needed index (first item in a tuple)

  ```
  (defn split-at-max [items]
     (->> items
          (map vector (rest (range)))
          (apply max-key second)
          first
          (#(split-at % items))))

  user> (split-at-max [-1 20 3 4 1 3 5 101 4 2 6 4])
  [(-1 20 3 4 1 3 5 101) (4 2 6 4)]
  ```

moreover you could easily modify it to be used with an arbitrary criteria for estimation the value.

```
(defn split-at-max [items & {identity-fn :by :or {identity-fn identity}}]
  (->> items
       (map vector (rest (range)))
       (apply max-key (comp identity-fn second))
       first
       (#(split-at % items))))
```

max by identity:

```
user> (split-at-max [-1 20 3 4 1 3 5 101 4 2 6 4])
[(-1 20 3 4 1 3 5 101) (4 2 6 4)]
```

max by size:

```
user> (split-at-max ["i" "wanna" "rock'n'roll" "all" "night" 
                     "and"  "party" "every" "day"] 
                    :by count)
[("i" "wanna" "rock'n'roll") ("all" "night" "and" "party" "every" "day")]
```

or by some external value for example:

```
user> (split-at-max [:a :b :c :d] :by {:a 0 :b 121 :c 2 :d -100})
[(:a :b) (:c :d)]
```

so to me it seems more functional (and for that more "clojure way"), though probably not the most productive.

Comment: Quite involved but really nice!

Comment: Well, that's why i said it was fun. Other solutions are definitely better

Answer (score 2):

If order who goes first doesn't matter you could use this

```
(def up5 [1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1 0])
(def up5max (apply max up5)

(->> up5 
     reverse 
     (split-with (partial > up5max)) 
     (map reverse))

#=> ((4 3 2 1 0) (1 2 3 4 5))
```

Answer (score 2):

If performance is important I'd do it like this:

```
(defn vec-split-at [idx v]
  (if (empty? v)
    [[] []]
    [(subvec v 0 idx) (subvec v idx)]))

(defn split-at-max [xs]
  (let [m-el (reduce-kv
               (fn [max k v]
                 (if (<= v (second max))
                   max
                   [k v])) [0 (first xs)] xs)]
    (if (vector? xs)
      (vec-split-at (-> m-el first inc) xs)
      (split-at (-> m-el first inc) xs))))

(split-at-max [1 10 10 1])
```

It should be `N + C` comparisons for vectors. Where C is relatively small.

Comment: This is only compatible with vectors or maps, because of using `reduce-kv`

Comment: Why `(if (vector? xs) ...)`? You're told `xs` is a vector. Besides, `xs` must be an associative collection with positional indices for `reduce-kv` and `split-at` to work. Also, you can push the `if` down: `((if vector? xs vec-split-at split-at) (-> m-el first inc) xs)`, but maybe we're not used to reading conditionals in operator position. Still the best on offer.

Comment: There appear to be some defects in the `reduce-kv` call: `<` should be `<=` to stick to *the first instance of the maximum value*, as the question requires; the `1` should be `0` to match the `first`; and the final `xs` might as well be `(rest xs)`, to avoid looking at the first element twice.

Comment: Thumbnail: You're right about all your comments! My version can certainly be improved. I realized to late that `reduce-kv` is so limited.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of making the first two corrections. The third was wrong: `(rest xs)` returns a sequence. `(subvec xs 1)` ought to work, but doesn't. Bug in `reduce-kv`?

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the `indexOf()` method with a combination of `count` and `take-while` if you would like to avoid bringing a Java method into Clojure world.

```
user> (def up5 [1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1])
#<Var@20c4449f: [1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1]>

user> (split-at (inc (count (take-while #(< % (apply max up5)) up5))) up5)
[(1 2 3 4 5) (4 3 2 1)]
```

However, I prefer the following solution to the former one, though this is longer than the index-based solution.

```
user> (let [x (apply max up5)
            [lhs rhs] (split-with #(< % x) up5)]
        [(conj (vec lhs) (first rhs)) (vec (next rhs))])
[[1 2 3 4 5] [4 3 2 1]]
```

Comment: bad idea! `(apply max up5)` would be called each time the predicate for take-while/split-with is being called. And it means a huge overhead. Should better first find max value, and then use it in a predicate.

Comment: Thank you for spotting the performance issue in my solution. I revised my answer.

Comment: @tnoda I think the problem still exists in your first example, `apply max up5` should be evaluated every time `take-while` wants to check its result with the next element of the collection (if i am not right correct me please...).

Answer (score 1):

First, given that `.indexOf` is listed in the [Clojure cheatsheet](http://clojure.org/cheatsheet), I think it's idiomatic to use it.

Here are two more alternatives:

This one is similar to tnoda's second solution:

```
(let [[a b c] (partition-by #(< % (apply max up5) up5)]
  [(concat a b) c])
;=> [(1 2 3 4 5) (4 3 2 1)]
```

This next one looks more complicated, but it's more elegant in one respect: It delays the effect of `<` in order to include the `=` item, so there's no need to use `conj` or `concat` afterwards to stick the `=` item back into the first sequence:

```
(let [the-max (apply max up5)]
  (loop [the-start []
         the-rest up5
         continue? true]
    (if continue?
      (let [this-one (first the-rest)]
        (recur (conj the-start this-one)
               (rest the-rest)
               (< this-one the-max)))
      [the-start the-rest])))
;=> [[1 2 3 4 5] (4 3 2 1)]
```

The second element of the result is a `clojure.lang.PersistentVector$ChunkedSeq`, btw.  For most purposes, the kind of sequence shouldn't matter, but you can apply `vec` to it if you really want a vector.  Likewise for the results of my first example.

Comment: The first version is accidentally quadratic and really shouldn't be used.

Comment: Thanks @Andre.  Too bad.  It's so simple, eve though it obviously does a lot of unnecessary work.  Maybe for small sequences ....

Answer (score 1):

I started with

```
(defn split-at-max [v]
  (let [m (apply max v)
        n (count (take-while #(> m %) v))]
    (split-at (inc n) v)))
```

This is clumsy. I should use `split-with` instead of `split-at`, avoiding the need to calculate `n`. However, we can modify it to use vectors throughout:

```
(defn split-at-max [v]
  (let [m (apply max v)
        n (loop [i 0]
            (if (= (v i) m) i (recur (inc i))))
        n (inc n)]
    [(subvec v 0 n) (subvec v n)]))
```

This avoids realizing the split sequences, so is faster in use.

The `loop` finds the first occurrence of the maximum element. Taking a hint from [@Mars](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33961984/1562315), we could use Java `ArrayList`'s `indexOf` method instead:

```
(defn split-at-max [v]
  (let [m (apply max v)
        n (inc (.indexOf v m))]
    [(subvec v 0 n) (subvec v n)]))
```

This is fast, concise, and clear.